# Adding text track to AVAsset prior to saving?

Tags: ios, video, swift2, avasset

I am wanting to record a video using the iPhone's built in camera and then add a text track before it gets saved, but I seem to have a few problems doing this.

```
extension VideoRecorderViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        if mediaType!.isEqualToString(kUTTypeMovie as String) {
            let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition(URL: info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL)

            print("track count: \(mixComposition.tracks.count)")
            print("mixComposition is \(mixComposition.readable)")

            // TODO insert tracks here
            // mixComposition.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,sourceAsset.duration), ofTrack: assetTrack, atTime: insertTime, error: nil)

            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

            let savePath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("extratrack-1234.mov")
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)              

            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            if (exporter != nil) {            
                exporter!.outputURL = url
                exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4

                exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        print("dispatch called")
                        self.exportDidFinish(exporter!)
                    })
                }                            
             }
         } 
    }
}
```

Trying this code the output for `mixComposition.readable` is `false`, the track count is zero and when we get to the exporter the instance is nil, probably due to the `AVMutableComposition` not loading the referenced file as I had expected.

Is there a way where I can load an existing video, add track to it and then save it. I want to avoid having to create the file from scratch and then re-adding the tracks individually and ensuring I don't lose any metadata in the process.

Note, I want to add the subtitle track as separate track, as opposed to a composite.